# Full vacuum on big table (2.7 TB)

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

I have big database which contains a table of 2.7TB of data. I deleted some records, and I want to reclaim the disk space.

However, i only have about 200 gb free disk space left. How can I do this?
The physical files of the 2.7 TB file are all splitted in 1 gb files.

For the vacuum full, will I need 2.7 TB of free disk space or 1 gb ?
How will I ever be able to run the full vacuum? I read something about the symbolic link to an other server drive but i'm not sure an other server has 3 TB of storage left.

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks!

Comment: It will takes as much extra space as the size of the new table and all of it's indexes. How much data did you delete?

Comment: thanks for your answer!
I think i deleted few gb's, nothing to crazy.

could i make a table dump to an other server and restore it in production to get rid of the deleted tuples?

Comment: Yes.  And it should compress pretty well while in the dumped state. But you will need to drop or truncate the table before the reload, so you will have downtime for as long as it takes to load and index that amount of data.  Hardly seems worthwhile for a few gig.

Comment: We are planning on deleting old documents so it could mean a +/- 500 gb difference. Thanks JJanes!

Comment: I have been looking at pg_repack. 
Could that solve my problem?

I can find alot of tutorials how to use it in Linux, but none how to use it in Windows?

Comment: No, pg_repack won't help you. Both vacuum full and pg_repack will first create a new table, copy all the necessary data into it, and build the indexes. Therefore, both methods are not suitable if there is not enough free space for a copy of the table. Perhaps pgcompacttable could help, but I haven't tested it on windows.